# Linked Server from x64 sql server to x64 Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I am having a sql server 2005 x64 SP2 server (9.00.5069.00 (X64)) on Windows 2003 server (Service Pack 2)

I would like to create a linked server from this server to an Oracle server which is running in x64 bit machine. I do have x86 Oracle client installed. Do I need to have x64 Oracle client also?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a 32-bit Oracle client installed (both the 32- and the 64-bit clients would be x86 clients)?  And I'm assuming that you have a 64-bit server given that you're running a 64-bit version of SQL Server.  Is that correct?  Why did you install a 32-bit Oracle client on a 64-bit Windows server?  Is there something running on the server that requires the 32-bit client libraries?

Comment: Yes, I do have a 32 bit sql server instance which uses the 32 bit Oracle client for doing some legacy day to day activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a linked server on a 64-bit SQL Server you will need a 64-bit driver to use for your destination.

32-bit drivers cannot be used for linked servers on a 64-bit SQL Server.

Comment: I did figure this out from a friend of mine. But thank you for the reply.